# RestSharp AdvancedResponseWriter in Unit tests

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq, restsharp

I use `AdvancedResponseWriter`  as depicted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31443111/process-restsharp-response-as-a-stream-after-checking-the-response-status) to save incoming stream in file. Code works fine:

```
var request = new RestRequest(uri)
    .AddUrlSegment("drillingProgramId", session.DrillingProgramId);
request.Method = Method.GET;
request.AdvancedResponseWriter = (stream, response) =>
{
    // Should be able to access response which is an IHttpResponse
    if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK) return;
    string tempFilePath = Path.GetTempPath() + session.SessionId;
    
    if (uri.EndsWith("initial")) tempFilePath += "_initial";
    if (uri.EndsWith("nnb")) tempFilePath += "_nnb";
    
    using var fileStream = File.Create(tempFilePath);
    stream.CopyTo(fileStream);
    filePathOne = tempFilePath;
};
await _download.ExecuteAsync(request);
```

But when I use `RestResponse` mock, action for `AdvancedResponseWriter` is not called. Here is code for mock:

```
mock
    .Setup(m => m.ExecuteAsync(It.IsAny<RestRequest>(), It.IsAny<CancellationToken>()))
    .ReturnsAsync(() => new RestResponse 
    {
        Content = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
        StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK,
        RawBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("gfgdfgdfgdfg")       
    });
```

I checked that response `Content`, `StatusCode` and `RawBytes` fields are filled, so my mock works. How to engage `AdvancedResponseWriter` with unit tests?

**UPDATE**

If I rewrite code without using stream and `AdvancedResponseWriter`, unit testing works as expected.

```
var request = new RestRequest(uri)
    .AddUrlSegment("drillingProgramId", session.DrillingProgramId);
request.Method = Method.GET;              
var response = await _download.ExecuteAsync(request);

if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK) return filePathOne;
string tempFilePath = Path.GetTempPath() + session.SessionId;

if (uri.EndsWith("initial")) tempFilePath += "_initial";
if (uri.EndsWith("nnb")) tempFilePath += "_nnb";

await File.WriteAllTextAsync(tempFilePath,response.Content);
filePathOne = tempFilePath;
```

Comment: You are mocking ExecuteAsync instead of Execute

Comment: Example is copy-pasted from another question, in my code I use ExecuteAsync. I'll edit info now

Comment: Are you sure that you are mocking the [right overload](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/blob/dev/src/RestSharp/RestClient.Async.cs#L65) of the `ExecuteAsync`?

Comment: I hit breakpoint inside mock during this test, so I'm sure

Comment: @MichaelSnytko Are you fine with the revised solution? If so, please leave a new post and mark it as the answer. If not then does the original question still stand?

Comment: @PeterCsala well I don't use streams in my solution, so original problem is not solved.  On other hand, I'm not really sure if streaming is useful in RestSharp case; how will it work for megabytes of data? When I check response in debugger, "Content" field is filled. I guess the question should stay  for someone in the future.